# plpgsql loop through query and update

Tags: postgresql, loops, sorting, sql-update, plpgsql

I have a table called `test` and I sort it by the upper range of a range called `daterange`. I want to take the order of this sorted data and save it in another column of the same table named `bc_order`.

The order of the sort must be saved in the `bc_order` column.

So I order the data I want, I loop through the results and I increase a counter every time, then update the `bc_order` column with the current counter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __a_bc_order() RETURNS void  AS $$
    DECLARE
        iterator integer := 1;
        r  test%rowtype;
    BEGIN
        for r in 
        select * from test where upper(test.daterange)<0 order by upper(test.daterange) DESC
        loop     
            update test SET bc_order  = iterator where test.id = test.id ;    
            iterator := iterator + 1;
        end loop ;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select __a_bc_order();
```

I was hoping can get something like

```
id        daterange     bc_order
14  [-3001011,-2000101) 1
21  [-3001202,-3000102) 2
19  [-3010102,-3000102) 3
22  [-4001202,-4000102) 4
23  [-4000702,-4000302) 5
27  [-6000401,-6000201) 6
26  [-6000501,-6000301) 7
```

but I get

```
id        daterange     bc_order
14  [-3001011,-2000101) 7
21  [-3001202,-3000102) 7
19  [-3010102,-3000102) 7
22  [-4001202,-4000102) 7
23  [-4000702,-4000302) 7
27  [-6000401,-6000201) 7
26  [-6000501,-6000301) 7
```

I guess there is an issue with the looping that I cannot fix. Please advice. I use PostgreSQL 10

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a loop or PL/pgSQL:

```
update test
  set bc_order = t.rn
from (
  select id, row_number() over (order by upper(daterange) desc) as rn
  from test
  upper(daterange) < 0 
) t
where t.id = test.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong.

```
update test SET bc_order  = iterator where test.id = test.id ;
```

it is effectively

```
update test SET bc_order  = iterator where true;
```

and it is exactly your result.

should be

```
update test SET bc_order  = iterator where test.id = r.id;
```

@a_horse_with_no_name helps well - what is possible with readable one SQL statement, should be done by one SQL query.